# How to import prisma in +page.svelte file?

Tags: prisma, sveltekit

I have this simple sveltekit, prisma test code.

I just want to import prisma in +page.svelte.

```js
// path /src/lib/database.ts
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
export const prisma = new PrismaClient()
```

```js
// path: /src/routes/+page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
import prisma from "$lib/database"
<script>
```

But it give me error.

```bash
undefined
Internal Error
```

If I remove `import` line , no error.

How can I fix this ?

P.S. update.

```js
// database.ts 
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
export default prisma

// +page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import  prisma  from "$lib/database";
</script>
```

-- or --

```js
// database.ts 
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
export const prisma = new PrismaClient()

// +page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import { prisma } from "$lib/database";
</script>
```

Both not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you import without curly braces, you're expecting a *default* export, you should either change your export to

```js
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
export default prisma
```

or if you plan to export multiple objects,

```js
import {prisma} from "$lib/database"
```

in your `+page.svelte`

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Sorry. It is not working.

Comment: What is the new error?

Comment: no new error.  same error
`
undefined
Internal Error
`

Comment: I just fount this error on browser. `manifest.js:23 Error: PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser.
In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues
    at new PrismaClient ` Why  can't I import in +page.svelte ?

Comment: This seems like an active issue based on how `@prisma/client` is a CommonJS module
related issues; https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5030 ; https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10404 maybe these can offer some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot import prisma on the client side because it is server only. You are only able to import it on a server component. You can create an api under src->api->thingyouwant->+server.js. Make a call to your database in the API and then in your client you can make a function that will hit your API and return the data.

```
+page.svelte
  //set empty array for things if getting array
  let thingyouwant= []
  //set param somehow for thingToSearch
  let thingToSearch = "thingy"

  async function getAllThings {

       const response =  await fetch('/api/things?thing=${thingToSearch}', {
                method: 'GET',
            });
        let newData = await response.json();
        thingyouwant = newData.message;

  
  onMount(async () => {
    getAllThings();
  })


}

+server.js (in the src-api-things directory)
/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */
export async function GET({ url }) {
//get the thing param sent in the fetch call
const thing= url.searchParams.get('thing')

const thingFromDB = -----call to database----

return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: thingFromDB }), { status: 200 })
}
```